# spring mongodb: getting sorted and paginated list of inner document

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have two document. User and Activities. Activities is a inner document.

```
@Document(collection="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String usertoken;
    private String firstname;
    private List<Activity> activities;
}

@Document
public class Activity {

    private Date date;

    private String text;
}
```

I am using spring mongo layer in my project. I wanted to query and get a paginated list of activities for a given user using query annotations. How could I achieve this?

```
@Query()
List<Activities> getActivities(usertoken, Pageable);
```